# Magnetization in a finite lattice Ising model generated with MC algorithm

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, ising-model

I generated an Ising model using a Monte-Carlo algorithm and then computed the absolute magnetization per unit volume: $|M|$ and magnetic susceptibility $\chi$ as a function of the temperature $T$ at different lattice spacing $L$. I do understand why $\chi$ shows different peak values and different width at different lattice spacing: this has to do with $\chi$ having a divergence in the infinite lattice spacing case and the more I increase the lattice the closer I get to this. What I don't understand is the dependence of the magnetization from the lattice spacing: at low values of L it's more like a line; at higher values, it's closer to what I would expect from Magnetization at curie temperature. My graph looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The lattice volume $V=L^3$

Comment: Typical values of $|M|$ will be of order $V^{-1/2} = L^{-3/2}$ (Gaussian fluctuations) when $T>T_c$, which is not small when $L=4$, so the expected value of $|M|$ will not be close to zero in this case... In any case, $L=4$ is really very small to investigate a phase transition.

Comment: I'm trying to find a source for this, but the phase transition is only "sharp" for large ensembles (after all, thermodynamics tends to work in the large-$N$ limit). As your ensemble gets smaller and smaller, the phase transition gets gentler and gentler.

Comment: @YvanVelenik do you have a source for this? I have to write an essay and would like a reference

Comment: Well, central limit theorems for the magnetization have been proved (e.g., in [this well-known paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103907978)), but they apply only in the thermodynamic limit. But for your essay, rather than plotting the average of $|M|$ over many realizations, you should draw the histogram: this will make it clear to you how large the fluctuations actually are and how this distribution concentrates on its expectation as $L$ becomes larger.

Comment: It also looks pretty bad because the range of (inverse) temperatures you use is rather narrow. Compare this with Figure 1.10 in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/). The latter shows finite-volume simulations similar to yours but for the 2d model (number of spins is thus $(2n+1)^2$ in this picture). Even for $n=5$, the transition does not look so bad once the full temperature range is shown (here mapped to the interval $[0,1]$ by a suitable function).